# ASP.NET Web API XmlMediaTypeFormatter not giving error on unknown element

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api2

I want to send back a BadRequest if I receive XML that has an unknown element, attribute etc present.

I have the following settings in my WebApiConfig

```
 config.Formatters.Clear();

config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.Add(new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter());

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

I managed to achieve this for JSON requests through setting the missing member handler, but how do I achieve the same thing with XML requests?

My models are just plain straight forward models, not decorated with anything.

```
public class Address
{        
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And my controller action is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Create(Address address){
   ...
}
```

If xml is sent through which is

```
<Address>
   <AddressId>myaddressid</AddressId>
   <UnknownElement>whatamidoing</UnknownElement>
</Address>
```

I want this to error so I can send a bad request response back.
At the moment I don't get any errors and the model state is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following:

1 - Create a Custom XmlMediaTypeFormatter overriding the CreateXmlSerializer method

```
public class CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override XmlSerializer CreateXmlSerializer(Type type)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        serializer.UnknownAttribute += (sender, args) => throw new Exception(args.ExpectedAttributes);
        serializer.UnknownElement += (sender, args) => throw new Exception(args.ExpectedElements);
        serializer.UnknownNode += (sender, args) => throw new Exception(args.Name);

        return serializer;
    }
}
```

I am throwing errors on the 'Unknown' elements etc so that the default code in the XmlMediaTypeFormatter adds these as errors to the ModelState.

2 - Set the Api Application to use my Custom implemenation

```
config.Formatters.Add(new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

3 - Look in the ModelState in the Controller/Action to see if there are any errors with exceptions - these are the errors that have been caused by deserialization issues

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid && ModelState.Values.Any(i => i.Errors.Any(j => j.Exception != null)))
{
    return BadRequest("Badly formatted request");
}
```